# Interdependent derived attributes in Ampersand?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, state, ampersand.js

I'd like to create Ampersand State representation of a vector which simultaneously holds information about it's polar and rectangular representation.

i.e. I would like the user to be able to do:

```
vector.angle = 90
vector.mag = 1
console.log vector.y #=> 1
```

-or-

```
vector.x = 0
vector.y = 1
console.log vector.angle #=> 90
```

Can anyone think of a way to do this with ampersand?

Answer (score 0):

This is the old question, but someone might need this. 
Right away I can think of one way to do this. You'd need to make all of your variables independent and then listen to changes to update other values. So you'd define in `props` of the model variables `angle`, `mag`, `x`, `y`, and then attach event listeners  in `initialize` of your view or somewhere else to each of these variables. For example, for `angle` you'd do something like this:

```
model.on('change:angle', function(model) {
    //first, calculate new x and y values. In your model you have a new angle value
    if (NEW_CALCULATED_X_VALUE != model.x || NEW_CALCULATED_Y_VALUE != model.y) {
        model.set({
            x: NEW_CALCULATED_X_VALUE
        }, {
            silent: true//I'm not triggering the 'change' event yet to avoid circular dependencies.
        }); 
        model.set({
            y: NEW_CALCULATED_Y_VALUE
        }, {
            silent: true
        });
        //now, once I've set all new values, I can trigger events.
        model.trigger('change:x', model); //this will trigger model.on('change:x'), but since based on this change angle and mag won't change, no circular dependency will appear.
        model.trigger('change:y', model);
    }

})
```

and repeat this for each of four variables (there is room for optimisation, but you get my idea. In order to avoid circular dependencies with this example you need to make sure that once you recalculate, for example, angle by using whatever x, you get the same angle.